# Can you tell me what plant this is (pic attached)?

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors

I took a small cutting of this, a few weeks ago. It is now four feet long and very tough.

Can anyone tell me what it is?

[image]

Comment: Pothos , Devil's ivy ,in asia it is called money plant but i dont know why

Comment: @OmiPenguin Sounds like an answer.

Comment: @OmiPenguin Yep. That's the one. _Epipremnum aureum_ [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipremnum_aureum). Thank you. If you post an answer, I will accept it and vote it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pothos, Devil's ivy, in Asia it is called money plant but I don't know why.